# Fun Dictionary Manipulation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

This is perfect for what I need an no one seems to be answering it:

So, I have a fun issue. I have some data that have a fun nested dictionary that I need to manipulate, but am having trouble. I can do it in pure python, but wanted to do the entire solution in Pandas so as to keep the code a little cleaner and not have to re-open the same files elsewhere.

I have the following Dataframe:

```
Id             Timezone             Data
957643         Pacific             {"California":{"city":"San Francisco","pop":"874961"}, {"Oregon":{"city":"Portland","pop":"645291"}}
973472         Eastern             {"New York":{"city":"New York","pop":"8419000"},{"Maine":{"city":"Portland","pop":"66595"}}
```

Desired output, a list of dictionaries, placing the Id and Timezone into each exploded dictionary while wrapping each in another State Data key so I can just output as JSON:

```
[{"State Data":{"State":"California","City":"San Francisco","Population":"874961","Id":"957643","Timezone":"Pacific"}}, {"State Data":{"State":"New York","City":"New York","Population":"8419000","Id":"973472","Timezone":"Eastern"}},{"State Data":{"State":"Oregon","City":"Portland","Population":"645291","Id":"957643","Timezone":"Pacific"}}, {"State Data":{"State":"Maine","City":"Portland","Population":"66595","Id":"973472","Timezone":"Eastern"}}]
```

The problem is that I need to, for the final data format to be ingested elsewhere, placing all states into their own dictionary and updating so the State has a State key attached. I've tried the iterrows method and apply with an axis of 1 but it ends up putting all Id's and timezones in each dictionary and updates accordingly.

A variation of below works in pure python when reading in the whole CSV, but not in Pandas (for reasons that are likely obvious for most).

```
output = []
entry = {}

for id_, time, data in the_states.iterrows():
        for state, other in data.items():
            entry['Id'] = id_
            entry['City'] = data.get('city')
            entry['Timezone'] = time
            entry['Population'] = data.get('pop')
            entry['State'] = state
            output.append({'State Data': entry})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might make it more clear the differences between this question and [Adding to a nested Dictionary in a Column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67960396/15497888)

Comment: That hasn’t been answered and is perfect for what I need

Comment: I almost closed this question because of how similar they look at first glance. I'm saying _highlight_ the difference between how they should be aggregated. So others don't vote to close...

Comment: The other doesn’t seem to exist anymore.

Comment: That would be true if SO didn't have [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67960396/revisions).

Comment: Indeed. It still hasn’t been answered. And works for my issue.

Comment: Lol, I know, it’s really strange. I appreciate the bluntness and being able to be better at both asking correctly and getting better. Thanks for the link, I’ll check it out. And as to the dictionary problem, I’ll continue scouring and playing. I’m thinking I can just do what he did, on the columns and map it. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the pd.to_dict() options? You can pass in different ways of presenting your data. orient=records or orient=index might help you. Docs are here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html.

Comment: I hadn’t! Thank you, I’ll give this a whirl and see if I can’t get my data to look like I want. Thank you!